# If we define static variable as global then its scope should be within that file but here I'm getting different result

Tags: c

```
//FILE1.c  
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include "FILE2.c" 
main() 
{
 printf("%d",i);
getch();
}


//FILE2.c

static int i=5;
```

Here I'm getting output `5`. Why so? It should be an error, isn't it?

Comment: This isn't C, replace `main()` by `int main(void)`.

Comment: `main()` is not legal C any more. You may want to get a newer C book.

Answer (score 5):

Because you included the source file `"FILE2.c"`(which is not recommended). The preprocessor simply replace the line `#include "FILE2.c"` with the contents of `"FILE2.c"`.

So there is a variable `i` in the file `FILE2.c` which you have known, but also another variable `i` in the file `FILE1.c`. Their scope is within their own file(to be precise, their own translation unit).

You should only include header files in C.

Comment: Then but the meaning of the line "If we define any static  variable as globally then the scope of that variable will be within that file only in wch its defined "...plz clear...

Comment: @user2487315 Because the after preprocessing, the variable `i` is indeed defined in both `File1.c` and `File2.c`, you need to understand what the preprocessor does for `#include` lines.

Comment: then how can i check the use of this line  "If we define any static variable as globally then the scope of that variable will be within that file only in wch its defined "  plz give proper example....

Comment: @user2487315 Remove the line `#include "FILE2.c"`, you'll see the error.

Comment: Perhaps one should add that this here defines *two* different variables named `i`, one in each compilation unit (`.o` file).

Comment: @JensGustedt: There are two variables named `i` only if both files are compiled.